# type or namespace name 'ModelName' [cs file under edmx/tt] does not exist in VS 2013 and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I upgraded a project to VS 2013 and EF 6 from VS 2012 and EF 5.  I keep getting a build error on this line:

```
using CsCta.CtaSqlModel;
```

(which I hadn't in the old version): 
    "type or namespace name 'CtaSqlModel' does not exist in the namespace 'CsCta'"

'CtaSqlModel' refers I think to a file under CtaSqlModel.edmx and CtaSqlModel.tt called CtaSqlModel.cs.  These are EntityFramework 6 files created from an existing database (DatabaseFirst).

The somewhat mysterious aspect is that removing the offending line "using CsCta.CtaSqlModel;" produces a zillion build errors on missing definitions (for the EF 6 dbcontext entities)--so it looks like the compiler is getting some useful information from that line even though it complains that it is invalid.
---Also,  if I change the line to "using CsCta.CtasqlModel;" (change in case) then I get the zillion build errors; when I change it back to the right case "using CsCta.CtaSqlModel;" then I get that one build error.  So the offending using statement is being recognized, sort of.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I resolved the issue some hours later but it is odd behavior.  I went through the code window and noticed errors with red lines (not on the build error list) and corrected them.  I then removed the problem "using" statement, and everything compiled fine--so apparently that line is not needed, or not with EF6.  I'll update again here if I discover another glitch.

Answer (score 0):

When moving an existing project from EF5 to EF6 you need to replace the T4 templates in your project since the types moved in EF6 and code generated for EF5 won't compile against EF6. I blogged about this a little bit [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/)